# Emscripten crash with mappedGlobals.find(name) != mappedGlobals.end()

Tags: c++, emscripten

I have a problem when I compiled Emscripten code with -s ASYNCIFY=1  and call an external library class.

```
_setjmpTable
Assertion failed: mappedGlobals.find(name) != mappedGlobals.end() ? true : (std::cerr << name.str << '\n', false), file C:\emslave\buildslave\win-tagbuilder\emsdk\binaryen\tag-1.38.29\src\asm2wasm.h, line 1659
shared:ERROR: 'C:/workspace/emsdk/clang/e1.38.29_64bit/binaryen\bin\asm2wasm hello.temp.asm.js --total-memory=16777216 --trap-mode=allow -O3 --mem-init=hello.js.mem --mem-base=1024 --wasm-only -o hello.wasm --mvp-features' failed (-1073740791)
```

The problem is mentioned in emscripten github issue [here](https://github.com/emscripten-core/emscripten/issues/5383#ref-issue-218269701)

The problem is because of the

> The asyncify pass moves some code out of main, and then it can't find
>   those local vars

as Emscripten author said

The problem happens when I call other class from external libraries ( .bc ) and compile with ASYNCIFY=1. However when I remove ASYNCIFY everything is alright.

I also found that If I add the code before

```
jmp_buf env;
if(!setjmp(env)) 
{
  longjmp(env,1);
  emscripten_sleep(1000);
}
```

The code can be compiled successfully but it crashes when I ran it on a browser

How to solve the problem since I have to use both ASYNCIFY and a class from external library?

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem when I use `emscripten_wget(...)` with `-s ASYNCIFY=1`.
I have to use `emscripten_async_wget` instead, it need not ASYNCIFY.

P.s. I use emscripten version 1.38.29.

Answer (score 0):

ASYNCIFY is a known bug according to [this](https://github.com/emscripten-core/emscripten/wiki/Emterpreter)

> There are some known bugs with ASYNCIFY on things like exceptions and
>   setjmp. The emterpreter has not been tested on those feature yet, so
>   it's unclear if it would work. Update: there are known issues with
>   doing and async operation when there is a try-catch (llvm invoke) on
>   the stack.

use EMTERPRETIFY instead of ASYNCIFY

```
FLAGS             +=  -s EMTERPRETIFY_FILE="data.binary"
FLAGS             +=  -s EMTERPRETIFY=1
FLAGS             +=  -s EMTERPRETIFY_ASYNC=1
```

instead

Answer (score 0):

Also when I disable webassembly with  WASM=0
it works fine too